# Datatables server side processing invalid Json

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter, datatable

Alright so I am working on a script for datatables server side processing and I ran into an error. Whenever I load the page I get an alert saying my Json is invalid. Though I've used Jsonlin to validate it and it said my json was valid.

So here is the Json I use for testing:

```
 { "draw": 1, "recordsTotal": 5, "recordsFiltered": 5, "data": [{ "first_name": "Airi", "last_name": "Satou", "position": "Accountant", "office": "Tokyo" }, { "first_name": "Garrett", "last_name": "Winters", "position": "Accountant", "office": "Tokyo" }, { "first_name": "Rhona", "last_name": "Davidson", "position": "Integration Specialist", "office": "Tokyo" }, { "first_name": "Sakura", "last_name": "Yamamoto", "position": "Support Engineer", "office": "Tokyo" }] }
```

And this is my datatable script

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    var dbColumns = getColumns("<?php echo $View; ?>",'proccesTable', "<?php echo base_url(); ?>", "<?PHP echo $ViewAction; ?>");

    $('#proccesTable').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax":{
            url: ' <?php echo base_url("admin/QAJAXCall/".$AJAXAction."/".$TableName); ?>',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: { data : dbColumns}
        },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "first_name" },
        { "data": "last_name" },
        { "data": "position" },
        { "data": "office" }
    ]
    });
});
```

In the post I just try to do something else which isn't doing anything with my json being returned. Though I've noticed, there is always a NULL at the end of my Json? This is how I return the json to my datatable:

```
 $array = '{
     "draw": 1,
     "recordsTotal": 5,
     "recordsFiltered": 5,
      "data": [{
         "first_name": "Airi",
         "last_name": "Satou",
         "position": "Accountant",
         "office": "Tokyo"
     }, {
         "first_name": "Garrett",
         "last_name": "Winters",
         "position": "Accountant",
         "office": "Tokyo"
     }, {
          "first_name": "Rhona",
          "last_name": "Davidson",
          "position": "Integration Specialist",
         "office": "Tokyo"
     }, {
         "first_name": "Sakura",
         "last_name": "Yamamoto",
         "position": "Support Engineer",
         "office": "Tokyo"
     }]
       }';
        echo $array;
```

I dont use echo json_encode($array) since the variable is json already. Is there any reason that this "NULL" is being sent back aswell??

Answer (score 0):

you can also use datatable library for codeigniter only in order to make correct JSON response.
so, it would be easy for you rather than creating response manually.

1. https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables
2. https://github.com/zepernick/Codeigniter-DataTables

Thanks

Comment: The reason being is that we're working on a small extra but to datatables where any user without programming experience would be able to name the data inside the tables. We simply add custom attributes to the <tr> where the user can tell what data the row should contain.